# Логирование состояний нити

Tags: java, многопоточность, логирование

Как отловить все состояния нити и залогировать их?

Есть код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
    Thread threadForLogging = new Thread();
    LoggingStateThread loggingStateThread = new LoggingStateThread(threadForLogging);

    loggingStateThread.start();
    threadForLogging.start();
    threadForLogging.interrupted();
}
```

В LoggingStateThread записано так:

```
public class LoggingStateThread extends Thread {
    public Thread threadForLogging;

    public LoggingStateThread(Thread threadForLogging)
    {
        this.threadForLogging = threadForLogging;
        setDaemon(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        State st;
        st = threadForLogging.getState();
        System.out.println(st);
        do
        {
            if (!st.equals(threadForLogging.getState())) {
                st = threadForLogging.getState();
                System.out.println(st);
            }
        } while (!st.equals(State.TERMINATED));
    }
}
```

Я понимаю, что потоки идут в своем собственном порядке. В том то и вопрос: как не пропускать эти состояния? Сделать это надо силами класса LoggingStateThread.

И да, я понимаю, что это можно сделать с помощью специальных библиотек, но хочется самому разобраться, как это работает.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState()
не?

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov не понял ответа. Я как бы в курсе, что возвращает getState()...

Comment: Тогда опишите, что значит не пропустить.
Если вы хотите какой-то определённый порядок то надо его явно установить блокировками, если нет то что значит "не пропустить"?

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov у нити в данном случае проходит три состояния: "NEW", "RUNNABLE" и "TERMINATED". Просто запустите код и все станет ясно.

Comment: Думаю такое можно сделать java.lang.reflect.Proxy или Javassist
написать прокси и явно кидать нотификацию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ: никак. Вы не можете «подписаться» на состояния потока. Представьте, что вы запустили поток, он уже отработал, а логгер тупит где-то с выводом ещё предыдущего сообщения (скажем, вы перенаправили стандартный вывод в файл на сетевом диске и там как раз flush надо сделать, а сеть отвалилась). Вы предлагаете текущему треду ждать в состоянии RUNNABLE, пока логирующий тред перестанет тупить? Но если текущий тред будет ждать, то он уже не будет всё равно RUNNABLE, он будет WAITING. Треды — слишком низкоуровневая структура и они должны работать быстро вне зависимости от внешних условий.

Если очень сильно хочется, можно написать java-agent, который перехватит вызовы методов класса java.lang.Thread и добавить соответствующие логи. Но и то это сложно, потому что, например, в состояние WAITING можно перевести тред разными способами.